# Add double quotes around all the fields in CSV file

Tags: csv, awk, sed, text-manipulation

I want to add quotes in all the fields of the CSV file.

My CSV file

```
$ cat file.csv
1,563,45645,example-text,/example/path,FILE,ftp://,11
```

Expected output

```
$ cat file.csv
"1","563","45645","example-text","/example/path","FILE","ftp://","11"
```

Comment: please add your own efforts too in future... easiest would be `sed 's/[^,]*/"&"/g'`

Comment: None of these answers are particularly robust in that they'll break if given input where some fields are already quoted, so here's a perl one-liner using the Text::CSV_XS module: `perl -MText::CSV_XS -e 'my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({always_quote=>1});while (my $r = $csv->getline(\*STDIN)) { $csv->say(\*STDOUT, $r) }' < file.csv` in case that's a possibility

Comment: @Shawn your statement is incorrect. My answer does handle that. The Perl is nice!

Comment: @kvantour Your awk one doesn't handle quoted fields with commas in them. Unless you **know** your input doesn't have stuff like that (Which very well might be the case for OP's data), naive splitting on commas is not the way to handle CSV data.

Comment: @Shawn valid point!

Comment: the python solution mentioned in the other question linked here is useful because it handles the "blah,blah" case too

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
sed "s/,/\",\"/g;s/\(.*\)/\"\1\"/" file.csv
```

explanation:

```
s/           # substitute
,/           # all ,
\",\"        # with ","
/g           # global on whole line
;            # next expression
s/           # substitute
\(.*\)/      # save all into arg1 (\1)
\"\1\"/      # change to "\1"
```

Comment: The last part can be reduced to `s/^\|$/"/g` and if you use single quotes you can get rid of all the back-slashes: `'s/,/","/g;s/^\|$/"/g'`

Answer (score 1):

There are many simple and direct ways to format your CSV file the way you want. However, if you want your CSV file to be [RFC 1410](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) compliant you have to be a bit more careful. Especially with rule 7:

> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote.  For example:

> ```
>     "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

> **<sub>source: [RFC 1410: Common Format and MIME Type for CSV Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)</sub>**

This gives the following awk solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     { 
       for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { 
         gsub("\042","\042\042",$i)
         sub("^\042\042","",$i)
         sub("\042\042$","",$i)
         $i="\042" $i "\042"
       }
     }1' file.csv
```

If, in addition, you want to be compliant with rule 1:

> 1. Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line
>    break (`CRLF`).  For example:

> ```
>     aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
> ```

```
    zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF
```

> **<sub>source: [RFC 1410: Common Format and MIME Type for CSV Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)</sub>**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; ORS="\r\n"}
     { 
       sub("\r$","")
       for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { 
         gsub("\042","\042\042",$i)
         sub("^\042\042","",$i)
         sub("\042\042$","",$i)
         $i="\042" $i "\042"
       }
     }1' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Perl

```
$ cat smc.txt
1,563,45645,example-text,/example/path,FILE,ftp://,11
$ perl -lpe ' s/([^,]+)/"$1"/g ' smc.txt
"1","563","45645","example-text","/example/path","FILE","ftp://","11"
$
```

or using the lookarounds

```
$ perl -lne  ' s/^|(?<=,)|(?=,)|$/"/g  ; print ' smc.txt
"1","563","45645","example-text","/example/path","FILE","ftp://","11"
$
```